# Safari doesn't respect `transform-origin` SVG attribute

Tags: svg, safari, transform

I'm trying to build an SVG using `transform` attribute. But while my SVG looks as expected in Chrome and Firefox it looks broken in Safari. It looks like Safari doesn't respect `transform-origin` attribute and always applies the `transform` like `transform-origin` has `"0 0"` value.

I need to animate `transform` attribute and I need the resulting SVG to look the same in all browsers. I tried to work around the issue by providing different values to `transform-box` CSS property, but without success.

Is there any workaround for the issue?

Below is an example illustrating the issue. All images should look the same. They look the same in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

figure {
  border: thin #c0c0c0 solid;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

figcaption {
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font: smaller sans-serif;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>1. Reference image</h1>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none" fill="black"/>
    <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
    
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="75" stroke="none" fill="blue"/>
    <line x1="100" y1="25" x2="100" y2="175" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    <line x1="25" y1="100" x2="175" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="none" fill="red"/>
    <line x1="100" y1="50" x2="100" y2="150" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="1"/>
    <line x1="50" y1="100" x2="150" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="1"/>
  
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="25" stroke="none" fill="yellow"/>
    <line x1="100" y1="75" x2="100" y2="125" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="0.5"/>
    <line x1="75" y1="100" x2="125" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="0.5"/>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>Figure 1. Reference image, <code>transform</code> is not used. All other images should look the same.</figcaption>
</figure>

<h1>2. <code>transform</code> applied to <code>&lt;g&gt;</code> element</h1>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <g id="target-g-1">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </g>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-g-1" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-g-1" fill="blue" transform="scale(0.75 0.75)" transform-origin="100 100"/>
    
    <svg x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <use href="#target-g-1" fill="red" transform="scale(0.5 0.5)" transform-origin="100 100"/>
      <use href="#target-g-1" fill="yellow" transform="scale(0.25 0.25)" transform-origin="100 100"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>

  <figcaption>Figure 2-1. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> has the same size as the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code>.</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <g id="target-g-2">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </g>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-g-2" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-g-2" fill="blue" transform="scale(0.75 0.75)" transform-origin="100 100"/>
    
    <svg x="0" y="50" width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
      <use href="#target-g-2" fill="red" transform="scale(0.5 0.5)" transform-origin="100 0"/>
      <use href="#target-g-2" fill="yellow" transform="scale(0.25 0.25)" transform-origin="100 33.3333"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>Figure 2-2. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is centered in the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> along single axis.</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <g id="target-g-3">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </g>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-g-3" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-g-3" fill="blue" transform="scale(0.75 0.75)" transform-origin="100 100"/>
    
    <svg x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <use href="#target-g-3" fill="red" transform="scale(0.5 0.5)" transform-origin="0 0"/>
      <use href="#target-g-3" fill="yellow" transform="scale(0.25 0.25)" transform-origin="33.3333 33.3333"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>Figure 2-3. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is centered in the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> along both axes.</figcaption>
</figure>

<h1>3. <code>transform</code> applied to <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> element</h1>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <svg id="target-svg-1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </svg>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-svg-1" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-svg-1" fill="blue" transform="scale(0.75 0.75)" transform-origin="100 100"/>
    
    <svg x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <use href="#target-svg-1" x="0" y="0" fill="red" transform="scale(0.5 0.5)" transform-origin="100 100"/>
      <use href="#target-svg-1" x="0" y="0" fill="yellow" transform="scale(0.25 0.25)" transform-origin="100 100"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>Figure 3-1. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> has the same size as the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code>.</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <svg id="target-svg-2a" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </svg>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-svg-2a" x="0" y="0" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-svg-2a" x="0" y="0" fill="blue" transform="scale(0.75 0.75)" transform-origin="100 100"/>
    
    <svg x="0" y="50" width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
      <use href="#target-svg-2a" x="0" y="-50" fill="red" transform="scale(0.5 0.5)" transform-origin="100 50"/>
      <use href="#target-svg-2a" x="0" y="-50" fill="yellow" transform="scale(0.25 0.25)" transform-origin="100 50"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>
    Figure 3-2a. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is centered in the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> along single axis.
    Transformed <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is shifted.
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <svg id="target-svg-2b" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </svg>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-svg-2b" x="0" y="0" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-svg-2b" x="0" y="0" fill="blue" transform="scale(0.75 0.75)" transform-origin="100 100"/>
    
    <svg x="0" y="50" width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
      <use href="#target-svg-2b" x="0" y="0" fill="red" transform="scale(0.5 0.5)" transform-origin="100 0"/>
      <use href="#target-svg-2b" x="0" y="0" fill="yellow" transform="scale(0.25 0.25)" transform-origin="100 33.333333"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>
    Figure 3-2b. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is centered in the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> along single axis.
    <code>transform-origin</code> is shifted.
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <svg id="target-svg-3a" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </svg>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-svg-3a" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-svg-3a" fill="blue" transform="scale(0.75 0.75)" transform-origin="100 100"/>
    
    <svg x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <use href="#target-svg-3a" x="-50" y="-50" fill="red" transform="scale(0.5 0.5)" transform-origin="50 50"/>
      <use href="#target-svg-3a" x="-50" y="-50" fill="yellow" transform="scale(0.25 0.25)" transform-origin="50 50"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>
    Figure 3-3a. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is centered in the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> along both axes.
    Transformed <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is shifted.
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <svg id="target-svg-3b" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </svg>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-svg-3b" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-svg-3b" fill="blue" transform="scale(0.75 0.75)" transform-origin="100 100"/>
    
    <svg x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <use href="#target-svg-3b" x="0" y="0" fill="red" transform="scale(0.5 0.5)" transform-origin="0 0"/>
      <use href="#target-svg-3b" x="0" y="0" fill="yellow" transform="scale(0.25 0.25)" transform-origin="33.333333 33.333333"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>
    Figure 3-3b. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is centered in the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> along both axes.
    <code>transform-origin</code> is shifted.
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: This sounds like a bug in WebKit that should be reported https://bugs.webkit.org/ — because Safari does claim to support `transform-origin`.

Comment: It is supported... in Technology Preview. So no need for a bug-report.

Comment: @Kaiido I have just tested it in Safari Technology Preview Release 123 (Safari 14.2, WebKit 15612.1.7.10) and it doesn't work as it should.

Comment: @sideshowbarker I found out that there is an existing Safari bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201854 opened in Oct 2019. Have to be mentioned on caniuse.com

Comment: Up to date TP is 16612.1.7.10

Comment: @Kaiido according to https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/ the latest release is 123. So, on the one hand, I have the latest Safari TP release, on the other hand, about window shows that it has WebKit 15612.1.7.10. Doesn't release "lock" WebKit version? How can I get the latest WebKit version?

Comment: I don't know, I'm on latest BigSur with all System updates up to date and there TP does support transform origin on SVG just fine. So it's not necessary to bother them with this, they're on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Safari has implemented very little of SVG 2 - so the safe way is to only use SVG 1.1 capabilities for cross-browser (there is no transform-origin in SVG 1.1).

The cross-browser way to do this in SVG 1.1. is to transform/translate to the origin, do the scale and then reverse the translation. Something like:

```
transform="translate(100 200) scale(0.5 0.5) translate(-100 -200)"
```

Using this technique, the snippet from the question would transform into:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

figure {
  border: thin #c0c0c0 solid;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  padding: 5px;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}

figcaption {
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #222;
  color: #fff;
  font: smaller sans-serif;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>1. Reference image</h1>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none" fill="black"/>
    <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
    
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="75" stroke="none" fill="blue"/>
    <line x1="100" y1="25" x2="100" y2="175" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    <line x1="25" y1="100" x2="175" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="1.5"/>
    
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" stroke="none" fill="red"/>
    <line x1="100" y1="50" x2="100" y2="150" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="1"/>
    <line x1="50" y1="100" x2="150" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="1"/>
  
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="25" stroke="none" fill="yellow"/>
    <line x1="100" y1="75" x2="100" y2="125" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="0.5"/>
    <line x1="75" y1="100" x2="125" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="0.5"/>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>Figure 1. Reference image, <code>transform</code> is not used. All other images should look the same.</figcaption>
</figure>

<h1>2. <code>transform</code> applied to <code>&lt;g&gt;</code> element</h1>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <g id="target-g-1">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </g>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-g-1" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-g-1" fill="blue" transform="translate(100 100) scale(0.75 0.75) translate(-100 -100)"/>
    
    <svg x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <use href="#target-g-1" fill="red" transform="translate(100 100) scale(0.5 0.5) translate(-100 -100)"/>
      <use href="#target-g-1" fill="yellow" transform="translate(100 100) scale(0.25 0.25) translate(-100 -100)"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>

  <figcaption>Figure 2-1. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> has the same size as the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code>.</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <g id="target-g-2">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </g>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-g-2" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-g-2" fill="blue" transform="translate(100 100) scale(0.75 0.75) translate(-100 -100)"/>
    
    <svg x="0" y="50" width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
      <use href="#target-g-2" fill="red" transform="translate(100 0) scale(0.5 0.5) translate(-100 -0)"/>
      <use href="#target-g-2" fill="yellow" transform="translate(100 33.3333) scale(0.25 0.25) translate(-100 -33.3333)"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>Figure 2-2. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is centered in the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> along single axis.</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <g id="target-g-3">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </g>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-g-3" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-g-3" fill="blue" transform="translate(100 100) scale(0.75 0.75) translate(-100 -100)"/>
    
    <svg x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <use href="#target-g-3" fill="red" transform="translate(0 0) scale(0.5 0.5) translate(-0 -0)"/>
      <use href="#target-g-3" fill="yellow" transform="translate(33.3333 33.3333) scale(0.25 0.25) translate(-33.3333 -33.3333)"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>Figure 2-3. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is centered in the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> along both axes.</figcaption>
</figure>

<h1>3. <code>transform</code> applied to <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> element</h1>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <svg id="target-svg-1" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </svg>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-svg-1" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-svg-1" fill="blue" transform="translate(100 100) scale(0.75 0.75) translate(-100 -100)"/>
    
    <svg x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
      <use href="#target-svg-1" x="0" y="0" fill="red" transform="translate(100 100) scale(0.5 0.5) translate(-100 -100)"/>
      <use href="#target-svg-1" x="0" y="0" fill="yellow" transform="translate(100 100) scale(0.25 0.25) translate(-100 -100)"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>Figure 3-1. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> has the same size as the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code>.</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <svg id="target-svg-2a" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </svg>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-svg-2a" x="0" y="0" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-svg-2a" x="0" y="0" fill="blue" transform="translate(100 100) scale(0.75 0.75) translate(-100 -100)"/>
    
    <svg x="0" y="50" width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
      <use href="#target-svg-2a" x="0" y="-50" fill="red" transform="translate(100 50) scale(0.5 0.5) translate(-100 -50)"/>
      <use href="#target-svg-2a" x="0" y="-50" fill="yellow" transform="translate(100 50) scale(0.25 0.25) translate(-100 -50)"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>
    Figure 3-2a. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is centered in the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> along single axis.
    Transformed <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is shifted.
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <svg id="target-svg-2b" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </svg>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-svg-2b" x="0" y="0" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-svg-2b" x="0" y="0" fill="blue" transform="translate(100 100) scale(0.75 0.75) translate(-100 -100)"/>
    
    <svg x="0" y="50" width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
      <use href="#target-svg-2b" x="0" y="0" fill="red" transform="translate(100 0) scale(0.5 0.5) translate(-100 0)"/>
      <use href="#target-svg-2b" x="0" y="0" fill="yellow" transform="translate(100 33.33333) scale(0.25 0.25) translate(-100 -33.33333)"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>
    Figure 3-2b. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is centered in the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> along single axis.
    <code>transform-origin</code> is shifted.
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <svg id="target-svg-3a" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </svg>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-svg-3a" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-svg-3a" fill="blue" transform="translate(100 100) scale(0.75 0.75) translate(-100 -100)"/>
    
    <svg x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <use href="#target-svg-3a" x="-50" y="-50" fill="red" transform="translate(50 50) scale(0.5 0.5) translate(-50 -50)"/>
      <use href="#target-svg-3a" x="-50" y="-50" fill="yellow" transform="translate(50 50) scale(0.25 0.25) translate(-50 -50)"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>
    Figure 3-3a. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is centered in the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> along both axes.
    Transformed <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is shifted.
  </figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <defs>
      <svg id="target-svg-3b" width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="none"/>
        <line x1="100" y1="0" x2="100" y2="200" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
        <line x1="0" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100" stroke="rebeccapurple" stroke-width="2"/>
      </svg>
    </defs>
    
    <use href="#target-svg-3b" fill="black"/>
    <use href="#target-svg-3b" fill="blue" transform="translate(100 100) scale(0.75 0.75) translate(-100 -100)"/>
    
    <svg x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <use href="#target-svg-3b" x="0" y="0" fill="red" transform="scale(0.5 0.5)"/>
      <use href="#target-svg-3b" x="0" y="0" fill="yellow" transform="translate(33.333333 33.333333) scale(0.25 0.25) translate(-33.333333 -33.333333)"/>
    </svg>
  </svg>
  <figcaption>
    Figure 3-3b. Nested <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> is centered in the outermost <code>&lt;svg&gt;</code> along both axes.
    <code>transform-origin</code> is shifted.
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Great answer, absolute life saver! A small note: if instead of SVG attributes you would like to use CSS, you should account for the default `transform-origin: 50% 50%` in your calculations, i.e. your opening would be: `translate(calc(originX% - 50%), calc(originY% - 50%))` ... using the `transform-origin="100 200"` example with a 200x200 viewbox, the equivalent CSS transform would be `transform: translate(0, 50%) scale(0.5) translate(0, -50%)`

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin the problem here is that the `transform-origin` attribute or the `transform-origin` CSS style in Safari is only applied to the `transform` style, not the attribute.

So if you change:

```
<use href="#target-g-1" fill="blue" transform="scale(0.75 0.75)" transform-origin="100 100"/>
```

to look like this:

```
<use href="#target-g-1" fill="blue" style="transform: scale(0.75, 0.75);" transform-origin="100 100"/>
```

or even this:

```
<use href="#target-g-1" fill="blue" style="transform: scale(0.75, 0.75);transform-origin:100px 100px"/>
```

it would work in all browsers.