# Mobile Transform Origin Property not consistent with Web

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, css-transforms

I have an application I am developing that allows users to drop "Pins" on an SVG. These pins can be moved around the underlying SVG and the coordinates are saved in a database. The pins also have a "center of mass" of bottom center, I store the coordinates of the tip of the pin, not the 0,0 origin of the pin icon.

I am trying to implement a functionality, that will allow the pins to show larger when zoomed out of the underlying SVG, and scale smaller when zooming in (think google maps, if you look at a zoomed out map of all restaurants and then zoom in, the pins get smaller and more spread out).

I have this feature working on desktop web, see images below
[image]

[image]

However, on mobile, the same code causes the pins to exist in a different location, and when zooming I can see them scaling down to the top left point, and not the center bottom like the desktop client.

[image]

[image]

JS Code that is creating the scaling styles and logic:

```js
if (instance) {
    instance.dispose();
    instance = panzoom($('#partialDiv')[0]);
    var pins = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.draggable'));
    instance.on('transform', function(pz) {

        var transform = instance.getTransform();
        pins.forEach(pin => {
            if (transform.scale > 10 && transform.scale < 18) {
                pin.setAttribute("transform", 'matrix(' +
                    15 / transform.scale + ', 0, 0, ' +
                    15 / transform.scale + ', ' +
                    pin.transform.baseVal[0].matrix.e + ', ' + pin.transform.baseVal[0].matrix.f + ')');
                var pinStyle = pin.style;
                pin.setAttribute("transform-origin", "" + pin.getBBox().width / 2 + " " + pin.getBBox().height + "0px");
                pinStyle.transformBox = 'fill-box';
                pin.style['-webkit-transform-origin-x'] = '50%';
                pin.style['-webkit-transform-origin-y'] = 'bottom';
                pinStyle.transformBox = 'fill-box';
            } else if (transform.scale > 18) {
                pin.setAttribute("transform", 'matrix(0.8, 0, 0, 0.8, ' +
                    pin.transform.baseVal[0].matrix.e + ', ' + pin.transform.baseVal[0].matrix.f + ')');
                var pinStyle = pin.style;
                pin.setAttribute("transform-origin", "" + pin.getBBox().width / 2 + " " + pin.getBBox().height + "0px");
                pinStyle.transformBox = 'fill-box';
                pin.style['-webkit-transform-origin-x'] = '50%';
                pin.style['-webkit-transform-origin-y'] = 'bottom';
            } else {
                pin.setAttribute("transform", 'matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, ' +
                    pin.transform.baseVal[0].matrix.e + ', ' + pin.transform.baseVal[0].matrix.f + ')');
                var pinStyle = pin.style;
                pin.setAttribute("transform-origin", "" + pin.getBBox().width / 2 + " " + pin.getBBox().height + "0px");
                pinStyle.transformBox = 'fill-box';
                pin.style['-webkit-transform-origin-x'] = '50%';
                pin.style['-webkit-transform-origin-y'] = 'bottom';

            }

        });
    });
}
```

Why would the pins be displayed at a different origin on Chrome Desktop vs. Chrome IOS? Same is true for other desktop browsers and Safari on mobile. I have tried variations of webkit styles but it does not seem to change this behavior. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: safari's handling of `transform-origin` is a bit quirky. You can also use translates as described here [Safari doesn't respect `transform-origin` SVG attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67057190/safari-doesnt-respect-transform-origin-svg-attribute#67057754)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of troubleshooting I learned that there is a bug on IOS webkit 16.2+ that does not allow transform-origin to work with a transform attribute. Only the transform being performed in CSS will work with a transform-origin style.

Useful resource for anyone having an issue similar to me:
https://caniuse.com/mdn-svg_attributes_presentation_transform-origin